# Parameter 0 of method entityManagerFactory in *.configuration.SecondaryDataSource required a bean of type '*.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having 2 database connection scenario, one with neo4j and one with mariadb. so wrote two config class to scan repositories and domain classes but getting below error while starting spring boot application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.nkt.nsw.uiv.uam.foo.repo"})
@Profile("UAM")
public class PrimarydataSource {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

  @Bean(name = "barDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
//    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("bar.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("bar.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("bar.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("bar.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
  }
 @Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.nkt.nsw.uiv.uam.foo.domain")
        .build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "barTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
      @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
  }

}




@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"com.nkt.nsw.uiv.uam.repository"})
@Profile("UAM")
public class SecondaryDataSource {

     @Autowired
        private Environment env;

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
//    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.data.neo4j.uri"));
//      dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.data.neo4j.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.data.neo4j.password"));

        return dataSource;
  }

@Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.nkt.nsw.uiv.uam.entities")
        .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
      @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

Maven `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nokia.nsw.uiv.uam</groupId>
    <artifactId>uiv-uam</artifactId>
    <version>19.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>uiv-uam</name>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <keycloak_version>6.0.0</keycloak_version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.nokia.nsw.uiv</groupId> <artifactId>uiv-core</artifactId> 
            <version>19.9-SNAPSHOT</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-authz-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak_version}</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
            <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nokia.nsw.uiv.uam.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>uiv-uam-core</artifactId>
            <version>19.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-graphdb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <!--<exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId> 
                        </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId> <artifactId>*</artifactId> 
                        </exclusion> -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>io.leangen.graphql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
                        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- <parent> <groupId>com.nokia.nsw.uiv</groupId> <artifactId>uiv-parent</artifactId> 
        <version>19.9-SNAPSHOT</version> </parent> -->

    <!-- <build> <plugins> <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> </plugin> </plugins> </build> -->

</project>
```

{"type":"log", "host":"N-20HEPF0WQ1U5", "level":"ERROR", "neid":"UIV-FRAMEWORK", "system":"UIV", "time":"2019-09-12T11:58:38.730Z", "timezone":"UTC", "log":"\r\n\r\n***************************\r\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\r\n***************************\r\n\r\nDescription:\r\n\r\nParameter 0 of method entityManagerFactory in com.nkt.nsw.uiv.uam.configuration.SecondaryDataSource required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' that could not be found.\r\n\r\n\r\nAction:\r\n\r\nConsider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' in your configuration.\r\n"}

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://135.250.138.117:7687
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=admin@123
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration,io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.autoconfigure.SpqrAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration
uam.aspect.enabled=false
uiv.kc.adminRealm=master
uiv.kc.adminUser=admin
uiv.kc.adminPassword=admin
uiv.kc.adminApp=uiv-app
uiv.kc.adminSecret=462fe347-d47f-4365-94ee-6aefff994ef2
uiv.kc.adminURL=https://135.250.138.48:8666/auth

bar.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://135.250.138.52:3306/METADATA
bar.datasource.username=METADATA
bar.datasource.password=METADATA
bar.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: For starters your `neo4j.uri` is wrong shouldn't it start with `jdbc:neo4j:bolt:` instead of just `bolt:`?

Comment: Deinum, This project is already working with neo4j setup I am trying to introduce mariadb  may be not an issue

Comment: It requires a bean that isn't available. Which is due to the exclusion of all those auto configurations.

Comment: @Deinum tried by removing above line application.properties file got below error,"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/nokia/nsw/uiv/uam/configuration/SecondaryDataSource.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Comment: Not sure if you need to remove all of them but the hibernate and datasource related once can go (they will automatically backoff due to the configured beans).

Comment: Same error Deinum !!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have several configurations and in your @SpringBootApplication you have excluded DataSourceAutoConfigration.class like:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfigration.class})
```

It is adviced to do because otherwise you get multiple beans of type DataSorce,... on initialization. If that is the case, you can remove the exclusion from

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

and mark all the beans in one of your configurations as @Primary, like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager", basePackages = 
    {"com.nkt.nsw.uiv.uam.foo.repo"})
@Profile("UAM")
public class PrimarydataSource {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "barDataSource")
    ...
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    ...
}
```